# GKE- default kube-proxy and other workloads are not healthy

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking, kube-proxy

I have created a new private cluster in Org/personal Google Project and i can see kube-proxy and few other workloads with DaemonSet is showing unhealthy. why these are unhealthy though created by GKE only and is there no impact of having these unhealthy system-workloads.  Kindly suggest to resolve issue.
Please refer screenshot for error-

Error - DaemonSet has no nodes selected

[gke-kubeproxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rpC6.png)